# Creating a variable via the form rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Value the variables written in variables @first_city, @last_city, @date_trip of the controller. Without creating an object in the database. Then pass the values of these variables to another page. It is possible to do that or not?

```
<%= form_for(@orders) do |f| %>
        <p>Выберите маршрут</p>


        <%= f.select(:first_city, @city_select, :value => :first_city, prompt: "Откуда")   %>

        <%= f.select(:last_city, @city_select, prompt: "Куда")   %>

        <%= f.text_field :date_trip  %><br>

        <%= f.submit "Дальше", class: "btn" %>
    <% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

However if you state

```
form_for(@orders)
```

it will automatically assume you are creating an Order.

However you can do

```
    form_for @order, :url => {:action => "action"}
```

create your own action and access those values trough

```
 order_params[]
```

And you can do whatever you want with that data

Hope i helped

Comment: The parameters are transferred, but the error "No route matches [POST] "/orderdate" "

Comment: On Routes.rb

post '/orderdate' => 'orders#orderdate'